# Laravel change password issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For Laravel change password I did like this but why it is not working.. Its not updating password. I have done login page, registration everything working. But this giving me lot of trouble. Below is my code.

```
        $returnValue = DB::table('users')->where('users_id', $users_id)->where('password', bcrypt($request->opassword))->update(['password'=>bcrypt($request->npassword)]);
    if($returnValue >= 1)
    {
        $success['message'] = "Password updated successfully..";
        return $this->sendResponse($success);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Entered Old password is not valid..";
        return $this->sendResponse($error);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your error?

Comment: Its not updating password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first import Hash at the top of the controller. like this below

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

After this , validate old password match with your database like this below

```
$user = User::findOrFail($users_id);

if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) { 
   $user->password = Hash::make($request->opassword);
   $user->update(); // $user->save();

   $success['message'] = "Password updated successfully..";
   return $this->sendResponse($success);

 } else {
   $error = "Entered Old password is not valid..";
   return $this->sendResponse($error);
 }
```

Try this.

Comment: Wow ...You are genious.. Its working for me.. Thank you so much.. I was trying this from last 3-4 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your compliment. ;P @AravindaMVNaik

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your keys:

```
    $returnValue = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $users_id)
        ->where('password', bcrypt($request->opassword))
        ->update(['password'=>bcrypt($request->npassword)]);
```